# Image of a circle under conformal map $1/z$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, plane-curves, mobius-transformation

The image of a circle under conformal map $1/z$ should be a circle, but how to prove it (or how to find the relationship between the two circles)?

$z = x + iy = d + a\exp(i\theta)$, where $a$ is the radius of the circle and $d$ is a real number, represents a circle with radius $a$ displaced along the real axis.

Now $w = u + iv = 1/z$; how to find the center position and radius of the transformed circle?

I just write $w = 1/(d + a\exp(i\theta))$ and after some algebra I get $$
u = \frac{d + a\cos(\theta)}{d^2 + a^2 + 2d\cos(\theta)}\quad\text{and}\quad
v = -\frac{a\cos(\theta)}{d^2 + a^2 + 2d\cos(\theta)},
$$
but then I don't know how to simplify it and get it to the form that looks like a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real points $d \pm a$ lie on a diameter of your circle. The image points $1/(d \pm a)$ lie on a diameter of the image circle, so the image circle has center
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{d - a} + \frac{1}{d + a}\right]
  = \frac{d}{d^{2} - a^{2}}
$$
and radius
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{1}{d - a} - \frac{1}{d + a}\right|
  = \frac{a}{|d^{2} - a^{2}|}.
$$

Alternatively, starting from
$$
(x - d)^{2} + y^{2} = a^{2}
$$
and substituting
$$
x = \frac{u}{u^{2} + v^{2}},\qquad
y = -\frac{v}{u^{2} + v^{2}}
$$
works.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the first part of just considering the two points on the read axis, but I don't quite get the substitution of x and y in terms of u and v

Comment: The formulas for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ give the real and imaginary parts of the complex reciprocal, i.e., $1/(x + iy) = u + iv$ (and _vice versa_), so substituting gives the equation of the image (in the $(u, v)$-plane) of your circle.