# image of circle after inversion

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadratics

Given a circle $C$ of radius $r$ and center $(x_0,y_0)$, what is the center and radius of $C$ after inversion in the unit circle?

A simpler question has been asked:
[Image of a circle under conformal map $1/z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562344/image-of-a-circle-under-conformal-map-1-z)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$ as the original circle. Performing the inversion means replacing $x$ by $\frac x{x^2+y^2}$ and $y$ by $\frac y{x^2+y^2}$. Abbreviating $d:=x^2+y^2$ and $f:=x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2$ one can write the circle after inversion as

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{x}{d}-x_0\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{d}-y_0\right)^2 &= r^2 \\
(x-x_0d)^2 + (y-y_0d)^2 &= (rd)^2 \\
x^2-2xx_0d+x_0^2d^2+y^2-2yy_0d+y_0^2d^2 &= r^2d^2 \\
d-2xx_0d+x_0^2d^2-2yy_0d+y_0^2d^2 &= r^2d^2 \\
1-2xx_0+x_0^2d-2yy_0+y_0^2d &= r^2d \\
(x^2+y^2)(x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2)-2xx_0-2yy_0+1 &= 0 \\
(x^2+y^2)f-2xx_0-2yy_0 &= -1 \\
(x^2+y^2)-2x\frac{x_0}f-2y\frac{y_0}f &= -\frac1f \\
\left(x^2-2x\frac{x_0}f\right) +
\left(y^2-2y\frac{y_0}f\right) &= -\frac1f \\
\left(x^2-2x\frac{x_0}f+\left(\frac{x_0}f\right)^2\right) +
\left(y^2-2y\frac{y_0}f+\left(\frac{y_0}f\right)^2\right) &=
\left(\frac{x_0}f\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y_0}f\right)^2 -\frac1f \\
\left(x-\frac{x_0}f\right)^2 + \left(y-\frac{y_0}f\right)^2 &=
\frac{x_0^2+y_0^2-f}{f^2} \\
\left(x-\frac{x_0}{x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2}\right)^2 + \left(y-\frac{y_0}{x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2}\right)^2 &=
\left(\frac{r}{x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2}\right)^2 \\
\end{align*}

So the new center would be at

$$\left(\frac{x_0}{x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2}, \frac{y_0}{x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2}\right)$$

and the new radius would be

$$\frac{r}{\left\lvert x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2\right\rvert}$$

Some sanity checks. If the denominator is zero, that means your circle passes through the origin, so its image will pass through infinity. Makes sense. If the original radius is zero, then so is the new one, as points map to points. Sane as well. And the direction of the new center matches that of the original center, as expected.

Comment: Great, thank you! I wasn't having faith that I would be able to simplify using the direct substitution. The trick behind your substitution that I wasn't getting is in line 5 when you divide through by d, which effectively reduces from a degree 4 back to a quadratic in x and y.

Comment: Hi, I know this is quite old by now, but I was looking for exactly what you provided here. I compared this with a numerical experiment where I was generating random circles and their inversions. I also calculated the inverse radius and position by iterative means. So, to get to the point, your equation for the new center in complex form is $z_0/(z_0z_0^*-r^2)$, but I find that it should be the conjugate of this. Or, negative $y_0$ in your equation. Do you have any comment on this? Thanks.

Comment: @CyeWaldman, it would seem to me that $z_0=i$ with $r=0$ would be a particularly good example to look at here. That's a circle of radius zero on the unit circle in positive direction along the imaginary axis. With my formula, the center stays where it is. If we conjugate, the center would move to the negative side of the imaginary axis. Which doesn't match circle inversion. Can this example help you find an error in your experiment setup? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @MvG Hi, and thanks for your reply. If I have $z_0=i$, the $1/z_0=-i$, and likewise, any point close to $z_0$ would end up close to $-i$, wouldn't it? My experiment simply takes a random $z_0$ and $r$ and then $z=z_0+re^{i\theta}$ and then $1/z$. In addition, as I said, I have alternative means of calculating the inversion position and center (working from $1/z$, of course). I have many circle packing programs where I create inversions, so I'm in a position to test this out in a *real world* situation. I will try to respond again with the results.

Comment: @CyeWaldman Inversion in the unit circle is $z\mapsto 1/z^*$, not just $z\mapsto 1/z$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Reciprocation but also the start of that article.

Comment: @MvG I understand what you are saying, but I do many types of conversions and I always take $z\mapsto 1/z$, which I believe is consistent with the Möbius transformation. So, for our purposes, let's just say that I am using the *reciprocal* of $z$. Thanks for your time, this has been helpful.

Comment: Circle inversion is not a Möbius transformation, it's an anti-Möbius transformation.