# Show that when a circle is transformed into a circle under $w = 1/z $ the center is never mapped onto the center of the image circle.

Tags: complex-analysis

In regards to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562344/image-of-a-circle-under-conformal-map-1-z) question, when a circle is transformed into a circle under the map $w = 1/z$ the center is never mapped onto the center of the image circle. I am concerned about the alternative approach the person providing the answer mentions. They say that we can show this result by using
$$
x = \frac{u}{u^{2} + v^{2}},\qquad
y = -\frac{v}{u^{2} + v^{2}}. \quad{(1)}
$$

I am able to get this substitution as follows from rewriting $z = 1/w$. However, to see an example of the claim, I consider the unit circle $|z| = x^2 + y^2 = 1.$ This has center at the origin. If I substitute the equations in (1) to this equation, I get $$x^2 + y^2 = \frac{1}{u^2 + v^2} = 1 \Rightarrow u^2 + v^2 = 1.$$ This still has center at the origin, which is not the claim. What am I doing wrong? Also, how could we generalize from this to show that the center is "never" mapped onto the center of the image circle using this approach?

Comment: What are you doing wrong?  The origin is not mapped to the origin.

Comment: What you’re doing wrong is believing that the claim is true. If the first circle has its center at the origin, the image circle does likewise. Moral of the story? It’s always useful to look for counterexamples, even when you think something’s true. When your proposed counterexample fails, you’ll probably gain insight into why the proposition is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $0$ is mapped to $\infty$, we need only consider circles that are neither around the origin nor pass through the origin.
If the radius is $r$ and the distance to the centre is $a$, the line through $0$ and the centre intersects the circle in two points at oriented distances $a+r$ and $a-r$ from the origin (and of course, the line contains the centre)
After inversion, these three points have oriented distances $\frac1{a+r}$, $\frac1a$, $\frac1{a-r}$ from the origin. For the centre to map to the centre, we need
$$ \frac1a=\frac12\left(\frac1{a+r}+\frac1{a-r}\right)=\frac{(a-r)+(a+r)}{2(a^2-r^2)}=\frac a{a^2-r^2}$$
and therefore $a^2=a^2-r^2$, i.e., $r=0$. Indeed such degenerate circles may be seen as an exception. Bu they are the only ones.